# HTTP 302 on page with PHP query in URL

Tags: php, http-status-code-302

I have a site that has multiple PHP queries in the URL like: `www.example.com?query=whatever`

This works fine and no issues except for one specific query on Firefox and MS Edge. All other queries work in these browsers and the Query in question works fine on Chrome.

After trying to test this I can see that it keeps getting a HTTP 302 response and keeps trying to redirect before it just times out and says the page isn't redirecting properly.

Any ideas why this is happening or suggestions of what I can look into regarding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the query that's causing issues? and how are your handling them?

Comment: I'm changing the country on my site, I just handle the $_GET variable like so:  `if(isset($_GET["country_id"])){//stuff here}`, it works fine for all other queries and there's loads of them for product and category ids as well as changing the language etc,.

Comment: Please paste the link also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure why this happened I had to rewrite the whole thing it just seemed to get stuck in a loop on certain browsers